# Personalize pandas boxplot with colors

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I've been trying to make a boxplot of some gender data that I divided into two sapareted dataframes, one for male, and one for female.
I managed to make the graph basically how I wanted it, but now I would like to make it look better. I'd like to make it look like a seaborn graph, but I wasn't able to find a way to make this using the seaborn library. I tried some ideas I found for coloring the pandas boxpplot, but nothing worked.

Is there a way to color these graphs? Or is there a way to make these side-by-side boxplots with seaborn?

```
dados_generos = dados_sem_zeros[["NU_NOTA_CN","NU_NOTA_CH","NU_NOTA_MT","NU_NOTA_LC","NU_NOTA_REDACAO", "TP_SEXO"]]
sexo_f = dados_generos[dados_generos["TP_SEXO"].str.contains("F")]
sexo_m = dados_generos[dados_generos["TP_SEXO"].str.contains("M")]

labels = ["CN", "CH", "MT", "LC", "REDAÇÃO"]
    
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,7), ncols=2, sharey=True)

#Setting axis titles
ax.set_xlabel('Provas')
ax2.set_xlabel('Provas')
ax.set_ylabel('Notas')

#Making plots
chart1 = sexo_f[provas].boxplot(ax=ax)
chart2 = sexo_m[provas].boxplot(ax=ax2)

#Setting axis labels
chart1.set_xticklabels(labels,rotation=45)
chart2.set_xticklabels(labels,rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

This is the result I have:

[image: Side-by-side boxplot usind pandas library]

This is the link to the data I'm using:
https://github.com/KarolDuarte/dados_generos/blob/main/dados_generos.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `sns` is best suitable for long form data, let's try melting the data and use `sns`.

```
# melting the data
plot_data = df.melt('TP_SEXO')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,7), ncols=2, sharey=True)

for ax, (gender, data) in zip(axes, plot_data.groupby('TP_SEXO')) :
    sns.boxplot(x='variable',y='value',data=data, ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked really well!
I'm a beginner, and not very good using the `.melt()`

Could you explain a bit more about the `for` loop? there are two parts that I'm specially confused: 1) the `(gender, data)` part, and 2) the `zip` part

Comment: `zip` is convenient in pairing items in several iterables (list, np.array,...) together. See, e.g. [this article](https://www.w3resource.com/python/built-in-function/zip.php). That said, `(gender, data)` comes from `plot_data.groupby()` which, as an iterable, loops over the pair `key, data_with_key`. For an example see [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-iterate-over-dataframe-groups-in-python-pandas/).

Comment: Thanks! I think I got at least the basics.